# Where does VS Code store the python interpreter setting?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have two folders, each containing a `.vscode` folder with identical `settings.json` files. But when I open them in VS Code (on Linux) and "Run without Debugging", one of them is run with:

```
/bin/python3
```

and the other with:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Where is this setting stored? i.e. how does VS Code know which interpreter to pick for a particular folder?

Comment: global or workspace `settings.json`

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned VS Code stores the interpreters in a sqlite database.

This is usually in `$HOME/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb` (or `$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/state.vscdb`)

The information is in the table `ItemTable` which has two columns: `key` and `value`. The value of the row with key=`ms-python.python` is a JSON-String with keys starting with `WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_` (among others) followed by the workspace path, and the interpreter path in their values.

The paths can be read with a simple python script:

```py
import sqlite3
import json
import pprint
connection = sqlite3.connect(
    '/home/username/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb')
cursor = connection.cursor()
result_list = cursor.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM ItemTable WHERE key='ms-python.python';").fetchall()
# we assume that there is a key 'ms-python.python'
value = result_list[0][1]
value_as_json = json.loads(value)
pprint.pprint({key: value for key, value in value_as_json.items()
              if key.startswith('WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_')})
```

If you are working in two different paths with `/path/to/workspace1` and `/path/to/workspace2` with two different interpreters (say `/usr/bin/python3` and `/path/to/venv/bin/python` you will get something like the following

```json
{'WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_/path/to/workspace1': '/usr/bin/python3',
 'WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_/path/to/workspace2': '/path/to/venv/bin/python'}
```

If you want to set the interpreter path you could do something like the following:

```py
workspace_folder = '/path/to/workspace'
python_interpreter = '/path/to/venv/bin/python'
key = f'WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_{workspace_folder}'
connection = sqlite3.connect(
    '/home/username/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb')
cursor = connection.cursor()
result_list = cursor.execute(
    "SELECT * FROM ItemTable WHERE key='ms-python.python';").fetchall()
# we assume that there is a key 'ms-python.python'
value = result_list[0][1]
value_as_json = json.loads(value)
# we simpy set or overwrite the key without any check
value_as_json[key] = python_interpreter
new_value = json.dumps(value_as_json)
cursor.execute(
    f"UPDATE ItemTable SET value='{new_value}' WHERE key='ms-python.python';")
connection.commit()
```

Please note that the script above doesn't check neither if the key is present nor if they are rows in the result. Add yourself the necessary checks.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, but don't forget to include these paths on MacOS: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb` and `~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/.../state.vscdb`.

Answer (score 3):

The setting for each workspace is in :

```
$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/*/state.vscdb
```

which are sqlite databases.

Comment: FYI, on Windows this %appdata%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb

Comment: yep. I don't know if this was true in the past, but I don't think it's true with today's latest release.

Comment: @starball You are talking about which platform, Windows, Linux or MacOS ?

Comment: all of them.⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @starball Can you give your path on Linux ?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations. but the path to workspaceStorage isn't the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Exact location of the Python interpreter path specified and how you can manually change is given officially in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

**Easiest way to change the python interpreter under usage:**

1. Open the command palette (ctrl+shift+p)
2. Type Python:Select Inerpreter
3. If the python interpreter you want is not listed then click on "Enter Interpreter Path" and click Find.
4. Choose the proper binary path of the python you want to use.

This way Settings file will automatically be updated and you don't have to worry about its location.

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the `python.defaultInterpreterPath` setting, then that will be used. Note that there used to be another similar setting called `python.pythonPath`, which now no longer exists (see also [this issue ticket comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17351#issuecomment-942735651)).

If you selected an interpreter through the UI and not via settings, then it's not stored in settings (see [related blogpost](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2021-release/#selecting-a-python-interpreter-no-longer-modifies-workspace-settings). Your selection from UI *used* to be stored in the `python.pythonpath` setting back when that was a thing). That's stored in internal workspace storage. The backing mechanism is `globalState` (see [the extension data storage API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage)). So you'd be looking under the user data directory (the default user data directory is one up from [the default settings file location's directory](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)), at `./User/globalStorage/state.vscdb`. There, the `ms-python.python` key's corresponding value contains JSON data with mappings for multi-root and non-multi-root workspace mappings for selected interpreter paths (`WORKSPACE_INTERPRETER_PATH_${...}` and `WORKSPACE_FOLDER_INTERPRETER_PATH_${...}` respectively). You could use something like SQLiteBrowser to read and edit this database file.

You can find the related source code in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/src/client/common/interpreterPathService.ts.