# I cant import tensorflow in Jupyter notebook on VSCode

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensorflow installed on my computer. When I run `pip show tensorflow` in the terminal I get this message shown.

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.10.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
```

but when I try to `import tensorflow as tf`  I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\jackb\Desktop\4th year\nn\cnn.ipynb Cell 10 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import tensorflow 
      2 from tensorflow import keras
      3 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

When I import tensorflow in a normal .py file it gives me no errors

Comment: Check the path for this setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405350/where-does-vscode-store-the-python-interpretter-setting

Comment: This is the typical case of having multiple python interpreters installed, a package is installed in only one interpreter/environment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the virtual environment activated and the interpreter you are using to debug is the required anaconda version.
[Python Interpreter Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlWbn.png)

For instance in the above image click on the version number of the interpreter and change the interpreter to the version in which you have installed your anaconda and tensorflow.[Changing Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1jYV.png)

In my case most latest version of anaconda is 3.10.6 but I am using 3.6.13 as I have activated my virtual environment "tensor" as in this case.

If the error isn't fixed yet, I would recommend you typing the following command in  the integrated terminal of VS Code with the specific project directory

```
activate {name_of_virtual_environment}
```

[Activating Virtual Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1ze4.png)
If you aren't aware of creating a new venv for your project then try referring to some online guide