# In VS Code, where are user settings saved and where to look for them?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-python

In vscode, I am quite confused where to change settings and where to find them.
There seems at least two places: Settings and Command Palette.

For a specific example, I am using vscode for Python.

I set my Python interpreter using

```
Command Palette->search: Python -> select: Python: Select Interpreter
```

It works for me. But I cannot find where this setting is stored.

I opened

```
Command Palette->search: Settings -> select: Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)
```

I cannot find my selected Python interpreter in settings.json. However, the interpreter works after vscode restarts.

**Is there any guideline where to look for a setting and where the setting is stored?**

'Where' means among 'Settings', 'Command palette', or other places that I am not aware of.

My vscode is version 1.77.3, 2023-04-12, on Windows 10

I would like to know:

- How vscode stores the user settings
- Why vscode spreads all the configuration around: some in settings.json, while others in state.vscdb.
- What the design philosophy behind this

I am suggested with this post [answer to my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405350/where-does-vscode-store-the-python-interpretter-setting). But this only answers 1 specific setting, not a general guideline.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode stores the interpreters in a sqlite database, on one of these paths:
`$HOME/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb`
`$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/state.vscdb`

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405350/where-does-vscode-store-the-python-interpretter-setting) answer.

Comment: thank you. following your lead, I found  that on Windows the file is 
 %appdata%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb

Comment: this only answers my specific example, not the general question I am asking. But thank you, I still learned a couple useful things from your answer.

Comment: the moderator asked me to write above words in order to re-open my question. I did it but my post is still closed. not sure how stackoverflow manages post these days.