# VS Code uses wrong interpreter with Poetry and Docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, python-poetry, vscode-remote

### Question

How can I get VS Code to default to my poetry interpreter?

### Background

I'm working on a Python project in a dev container based on a Debian image, with the Python extension installed in the container. I use Poetry for dependency management. For debug simplicity I'm running as root.

Poetry is successfully installed to `/opt/poetry` using a [manual install](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-manually). I run `poetry install` from my mounted code at `/myproject`, and Poetry correctly creates a venv outside my mounted volume at `/root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/myproject-somehash-py3.11`.

### Expected behavior

When I open a .py file for editing, I expect VS Code to select the Python interpreter, based on the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter):

> If an interpreter hasn't been specified, then the Python extension
> automatically selects the interpreter with the highest version in the
> following priority order:
>
> 1. Virtual environments located directly under the workspace folder.
> 2. Virtual environments related to the workspace but stored globally. For
>    example, Pipenv or Poetry environments that are located outside of the
>    workspace folder.
> 3. Globally installed interpreters. For example, the
>    ones found in /usr/local/bin, C:\python38, etc.

### Actual (surprising) behavior

- VS Code (technically it's Python extension, I believe) defaults to the global interpreter at `/user/local/bin/python`.
- It **does** find and display the correct Poetry interpreter, in the "Select Interpreter" dialog, but it does not default to that interpreter, which is the behavior I want:

[image: screencap of interpreter selection window]

- If I select the Poetry interpreter manually, this resolves the problem. This isn't a scalable solution (I want team members to be able to "grab and go" with the dev container).
- I cannot just add the path directly to the interpreter because Poetry adds a hash to the virtual environment folder name (eg. `/virtualenvs/myproject-45HY9SC-py3.11/path to python`
- I cannot use a .venv in the project root - this is a solution used by some but will not work for my team.

### Potential root cause

I've noticed that inside the venv, `bin/python` symlinks to `/user/local/bin/python`. Could Python be following this to the global python and thus "skipping" the poetry Python? Surely that can't be the desired behavior, given the documentation, so I'm skeptical.

Note: Poetry offers a setting to [always copy](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsoptionsalways-copy) rather than symlink, but apparently Python is excepted from this setting (it still symlinks).

Comment: you might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810406/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way, you can try to add `"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path/to/your/poerty/interpreter",` to your `settings.json` in `.vscode` folder to set the default Python Interpreter.